# Is there no pthread library in bionic libc?

Tags: pthreads, libc, bionic

I'm using a toolchain to cross compile some library which is dependent on lpthread for android. It had bionic version of libc. It says lpthred cannot be found and there is no libpthread.so to be found in the toolchain. So is there no pthread library in bionic libc? If yes, hat do I need to do to resolve this dependency? If not, how can I get pthread source so that I can create a libpthread.so by cross compiling?

Answer (score 1):

Bionic has the pthread functions in libc itself.  There is no need to link a separate threads library.